# Javascript Promise: can't get the return value out of my function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I can not get the return object out of my function, so I can reuse it in the next function which should be called by my `promise.then()`.
Struggling with researching, and can not find the solution.

**`engine.log` is basically equivalent to `console.log` in my application.**

```
firstRequest
    .then( function (result) {
            return secondRequest(result)
        },
        error => engine.log(error)
    )
    .then(
        result => engine.log(result), // result is undefined, need the object here
    )

let firstRequest = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.simpleRequest({
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': theUrl,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'timeout': 6000,
        }, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                engine.log("Error: " + error)
                reject()
            }

            if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                engine.log("HTTP Error: " + response.status)
                reject()
            }

            myObject = JSON.parse(response.data)
            resolve(myObject)
        })
});

function secondRequest(request) {
    http.simpleRequest({
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': theSecondUrl,
        'dataType': 'json',
        'timeout': 6000,
    }, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            engine.log("Error: " + error);
        }

        if (response.statusCode != 200) {
            engine.log("HTTP Error: " + response.status);
        }

        myObject = JSON.parse(response.data)
        return myObject // this is not being returned, to the .then()
    })
}
```

Comment: add return to `http.simpleRequest`. i:e `return http.simpleRequest({})`.

Comment: just to clarify: after hours of trying to solve my issue i can not do it. I am not asking this question before doing my research.

Comment: you don't wait for the response from secondRequest.  Presume that is async  ? If so it immediately returns undefined no ?  You would need to wrap secondRequest in a promise as well

Comment: @random this helped. I'm getting true instead of undefined now. How can i get my object now?

Comment: why is your second function not also wrapping the http.request in a promise, and returning that? It's still going to be just as async as in the first function, and you can't "return" anything until it finishes.

Comment: `return` is always from the related function scope it resides in. In your case `function (error, response) { /*...*/ return myObject; }`. `secondRequest` has no `return`, and therefore always returns `undefined`, per default. Aside from any semantical problems, this is the first and foremost problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
If i do that PHPStorm tells me 'promise returned from promise is ignored'.
And in my log, it just outputs my entire function (which contains the promise too) in plaintext.

I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I see redundant code, so I would consolidate your requests into a single more generic function.  It seems your desire not to do this is you feel you have to pass a 'request' parameter to your second function, but notice that you never use it.  Just pass a url in both cases.

In your generic function, which below i'm calling 'makeRequest', be sure to return the promise, or else you'll get undefined.  Also, be sure to call `resolve` on the parsed object, not `return`;

Also, I'd use `catch` for your errors, that way you'll catch it whenever an error occurs, whether it's in the first `then` or the second one.

This is untested, by the way, but I think the general points are in there.

```
makeRequest('somewhere')
.then(result => makeRequest('theSecondUrl'))
.then(result => engine.log(result))
.catch(error => engine.log(error));

function makeRequest (url, method, datatype, timeout) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        http.simpleRequest({
            'method': method || 'GET',
            'url': url,
            'dataType': datatype || 'json',
            'timeout': timeout || 6000,
        }, function (error, response) {

            if (error) {
                engine.log("Error: " + error)
                reject()
            }

            if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                engine.log("HTTP Error: " + response.status)
                reject()
            }

            // use 'let' or else you've made a globally scoped variable
            let parsed = JSON.parse(response.data) 
            resolve(parsed);

        });

    })

}
```

Comment: Just to defend my uncondensed code. I usually write my code messy until i get it working, then i condense the working parts to a reasonable extent. 

I'll try this tomorrow morning, thanks alot!

Comment: @Frizzant, that's a typical habit earlier in a career.  But a little humble advice, if you identify an opportunity for an abstraction you should be quicker to implement it (even in earlier stages) or else you've got more to sift through when you're troubleshooting.  In this case, you had some problems in one function that didn't exist in the other and visa versa.  So in essence you doubled your bugs.  And when you fix one function, you may not even know it because the other is still giving you grief.

Comment: good point. Thanks for that, i'll take this comment in my pocket, and let it remind me everytime i write code :-)
I guess, good habits.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript promises are asynchronous. Meaning they are resolved in the event loop, if the promise is resolved as soon as your call to `.then()` callback, then you will get the value in the next function as you expect.

Javascript promises are made **asynchronous** since typical API calls or database retrieving may involve network delays or any other delays to return the data. Thus the users will see these delays as performance issues. To avoid this kind of effect Javascript **event loop** is doing its job as running promises **asynchronously**. Meaning the code after promises is run most probably before it gets resolved or rejected. Therefore your next function will not have the value of first promise when its code is run. 
In the next iteration or 1+ iterations of the event loop, your promise may get resolved/rejected and then may have populated with the corresponding value.

The solution =>

You should use async await to make any asynchronous code synchronous in javascript.

You could read more about it here.
https://javascript.info/async-await